# Crash Introductory Texts on Group Theory **for Python Programmers**

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, algorithms

I am solving a problem for the Google Foo.Bar challenge that utilizes **Burnside's Lemma**, a (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)) Very Important Development in Group Theory. One catch - I know nothing about Group Theory, much less how to implement it in the Python language. I have ~ one week to solve and implement my solution, so I'm looking for a text on Group Theory that can teach me all the essentials, cover Burnside's Lemma, and do so in a manner easily digestible and formulated for programmers. I'm coding in Python, so extra points if the text focuses on that.

Abstract Algebra looks to be a pretty powerful tool for programming and data analysis, so if the text includes related fields (Graph Theory, Set Theory, Order Theory...) BONUS bonus points. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To understand Burnside's lemma, wikipedia is sufficient.

Comment: My favorite text was by Herstein: Topics In Algebra.  However, given the nature of the project, I recommend a tutor or expert to guide your journey.  The essence is that groups allow you to divide up a set by symmetry type, and so you can count things by knowing (roughly) how many types and what sizes they are.  Also, this is better on math.stackexchange.  Gerhard "Keep Studying Group Theory Afterwards" Paseman, 2017.03.26.

Comment: This link at [MSE meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has many different Polya / Burnside computations by various users.

Answer (score 1):

[SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/) builds upon a lot of Python. You can go to [Groups API](http://doc.sagemath.org/pdf/en/reference/groups/groups.pdf) to find the features implemented from Finite Group Theory.